# Subset R rasterstacks based on difference in grid cell number on each clumps

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I want to create subsets of raster stacks and write them as new stacks when the difference between the previous layer and the next layer is all NA following each clump of the raster layers.   Without clumps, I would achieve this by following Robert's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66321413/5959719) ( as below in script). However, I want to run this by considering the clumps too. There may be 1 or 2 clumps in each layer.  So starting from `layer 1` in the example data stack below, I want to identify the clumps numbers and for each clump, create a subset of raster stacks until there are no-overlapping pixels between the previous and next layers (i.e., the difference between the two layers is all `NA`). So I want is; starting from `layer 1`, for each clump, retain all the layers that have at least 1 common pixel between the previous and next layer, write them as a 1 stack, and move to the next.
In the sample `r_stk`, I want to retain layers 1:8 for clump 1 (top) assign them as 1 stack, run for clump 2 (bottom), and again retain layers 1:5 assign them as a new stack, and so on.
Below are the sample data and code that would work fine following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326463/5959719) if there would be no clumps.

```
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)

#Create null raster, fill values and get stack with clumps 
r<-raster(extent(-180,-140,34,83),
          crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0",
          resolution=10, vals=NULL)
r
#Make series of raters with clumps and stack
r1<-r
values(r1)<-c(70,69,NA,NA,73,70,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,100,99,NaN,NA,101,99,76,NA)
r2<-r
values(r2)<-c(89,81,72,NA,87,77,69,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,89,99,NaN,NA,89,100,84,NA)
r3<-r
values(r3)<-c(112,103,86,76,90,82,78,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,79,93,NaN,NA,78,93,88,NA)
r4<-r
values(r4)<-c(125,115,98,88,84,81,82,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,69,81,NaN,NA,69,80,83,NA)
r5<-r
values(r5)<-c(132,125,110,100,77,76,82,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NaN,71,NaN,NA,70,71,74,NA)
r6<-r
values(r6)<-c(118,114,103,93,72,75,77,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r7<-r
values(r7)<-c(98,92,76,69,70,70,76,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r8<-r
values(r8)<-c(76,73,68,NA,76,73,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r9<-r
values(r9)<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

r_stk<-stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9)
plot(r_stk) #raster stack with clumps
```

Works fine if i remove smaller clump and keep only one clump per layer however
i want to run this for each clump on each layer
I guess, i am trying to run one additional for loop on top of the script
below that consider clumps but could not make it successfully run

```
singleclump_lst<-list()
for (i in 1: nlayers(r_stk)){
  rasi<-subset(r_stk,i)
  #Classify based on clumps
  clumps<-clump(rasi,directions=8)
  clumpFreq2 <- as.data.frame(freq(clumps))
  clumpFreq_na2<-clumpFreq2%>%
    drop_na()
  clumpFreq_na2
  excludeID_i <-clumpFreq_na2$value[which(clumpFreq_na2$count == max(clumpFreq_na2$count))]
  excludeID_i
  subNA_i <- function(a, b) {
    a[!b %in% excludeID_i] <- NA
    return(a)}
  rasclmp_i<-overlay(rasi,clumps,fun=subNA_i)
  
  singleclump_lst[[i]]<-rasclmp_i
}

rr_stk<-stack(singleclump_lst)  
rr_stk
plot(rr_stk)
out <- lst <- list()
nc <- ncell(rr_stk)   
for (i in 1:nlayers(rr_stk)) {
  if (i==1) {
    j <- 1
    s <- rr_stk[[i]]
  } else {
    s <- s + rr_stk[[i]]
  }
  if (freq(s, value=NA) == nc) {
    ii <- max(j, i-1)   
    out <- c(out, rr_stk[[j:ii]])
    s <- rr_stk[[i]]
    j <- i
  }
}
out <- c(out, rr_stk[[j:i]])
out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(extent(-180,-140,34,83), nrow=5, ncol=4,
          crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
values(b) <- cbind(
c(70,69,NA,NA,73,70,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,100,99,NaN,NA,101,99,76,NA),
c(89,81,72,NA,87,77,69,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,89,99,NaN,NA,89,100,84,NA),
c(112,103,86,76,90,82,78,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,79,93,NaN,NA,78,93,88,NA),
c(125,115,98,88,84,81,82,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,69,81,NaN,NA,69,80,83,NA),
c(132,125,110,100,77,76,82,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NaN,71,NaN,NA,70,71,74,NA),
c(118,114,103,93,72,75,77,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
c(98,92,76,69,70,70,76,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
c(76,73,68,NA,76,73,NaN,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

The solution without clumps (that is, for a single clump) as in the previous answer, but wrapped into a function

```
one_clump <- function(r_stk) {
    out <- lst <- list()
    nc <- ncell(r_stk)   
    for (i in 1:nlayers(r_stk)) {
        if (i==1) {
            j <- 1
            s <- r_stk[[i]]
        } else {
            s <- s + r_stk[[i]]
        }
        if (freq(s, value=NA) == nc) {
            ii <- max(j, i-1)   
            out <- c(out, r_stk[[j:ii]])
            s <- r_stk[[i]]
            j <- i
        }
    }
    out <- c(out, r_stk[[j:i]])
    out
}
```

Get the clumps and their unique IDs

```
clm <- clump(b[[1]])
u <- unique(clm)
```

A function that masks out the data for a single clump

```
f <- function(i) {
    rr <- clm == i
    bb <- mask(b, rr, maskvalue=0)
    one_clump(bb)
}
```

Call `f` for each ID

```
x <- lapply(u, f)
```

x is a list. Each element is the result for one clump

```
length(x) 
#2
```

The list for clump #1

```
r1 <- x[[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, greatly appreciated, however it works only when `clm<-clump(b[[1]])`. For example, if I use `clm <- clump(b[[2]])` the results are all layers with some layers indicating multiple clumps while I expect only lower clumps and from layer 1 to 5 only.

Comment: `clm<-clump(b[[1]])` detects the clumps in the starting state.  Why would you do `clm<-clump(b[[2]])`? Either way, perhaps you can subset b instead?